# Does there exist any non-trivial square matrices of dimension $n$ with power cycles of less than $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation, cyclic-groups

Earlier I was faced with the matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
                  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which cycles (for lack of a better word) after an 8th power. So for example:

$$A^1=A^9$$

What I'm wondering is whether it is possible for a square matrix of ***reals*** to "cycle" in fewer powers than its dimension? For example does there exist a square matrix where

$$M_{18\text{x}18}^1=M^{17}$$
$$\text{or probably a simpler case}$$
$$M_{4\text{x}4}^1=M^3$$

Comment: There's always the identity matrix.

Comment: @TheoBendit - that's why I specified "non-trivial" in the title. I don't know if non-trivial is typically applied to the identity matrix, but I feel like the identity matrix is kind of a cop out.

Comment: Ha, so you did! My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$A(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix} $$
Then $A(\theta)^n = A(n\theta)$.  Now you should be able to generate matrices of any dimension greater than equal to 2, and so that it cycles after whatever power you like.

(Your example is $\theta = \pi/4$.)

Comment: Interesting! My only question is whether or not there exists a matrix with a less trivial lower right-hand portion.

Comment: Take a random invertible matrix $B$, and consider $B A(\theta) B^{-1}$.